# Generating a random number based off normal distribution in matlab

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution, numerical-integration

I am trying to generate a random number based off of normal distribution traits that I have (mean and standard deviation). I do NOT have the Statistics and Machine Learning toolbox.

I know one way to do it would be to randomly generate a random number `r` from 0 to 1 and find the value that gives a probability of that random number. I can do this by entering the standard normal function

```
f= @(y) (1/(1*2.50663))*exp(-((y).^2)/(2*1^2))
```

and solving for

```
r=integral(f,-Inf,z)
```

and then extrapolating from that z-value to the final answer `X` with the equation

```
z=(X-mew)/sigma
```

But as far as I know, there is no matlab command that allows you to solve for x where x is the limit of an integral. Is there a way to do this, or is there a better way to randomly generate this number?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`randn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) function which yields random numbers pulled from a standard normal distribution with a zero mean and a standard deviation of 1. To alter this distribution, you can multiply the output of `randn` by your desired standard deviation and then add your desired mean.

```
% Define the distribution that you'd like to get
mu = 2.5;
sigma = 2.0;

% You can any size matrix of values
sz = [10000 1];

value = (randn(sz) * sigma) + mu;

%   mean(value)
%       2.4696
%
%   std(value)
%       1.9939
```

If you just want a single number from the distribution, you can use the no-input version of `randn` to yield a scalar

```
value = (randn * sigma) + mu;
```

Comment: Wow, perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Just for the fun of it, you can generate a Gaussian random variable using a uniform random generator:

- The logarithm of a uniform random variable on (0,1) has an exponential distribution
- The square root of that has a Rayleigh distribution
- Multiply by the cosine (or sine) of a uniform random variable on (0,2*pi) and the result is Gaussian. You need to multiply by sqrt(2) to normalize.

The obtained Gaussian variable is normalized (zero mean, unit standard deviation). If you need specific mean and standard deviation, multiply by the latter and then add the former.

Example (normalized Gaussian):

```
m = 1; n = 1e5; % desired output size
x = sqrt(-2*log(rand(m,n))).*cos(2*pi*rand(m,n));
```

Check:

```
>> mean(x)
ans =
  -0.001194631660594
>> std(x)
ans =
   0.999770464360453
>> histogram(x,41)
```

[image]